# What is the use of this spring class BatchPreparedStatementSetter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

Can anyone give me short description about his spring class

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter
```

([JavaDoc API Link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/core/BatchPreparedStatementSetter.html))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's used for bulk insertion of many rows at once.

[This code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/UseBatchPreparedStatementSetter.htm) will illustrate how it's used.

Take a good look at `importEmployees` method, and everything should become clear.

Answer (score 0):

**batchUpdate can be done using JdbcTemplate batchUpdate method as follows..**

```
public int[] batchUpdate(final List<Actor> actors) {
int[] updateCounts = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("update t_actor set first_name = ?, " +
"last_name = ? where id = ?",
new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
ps.setString(1, actors.get(i).getFirstName());
ps.setString(2, actors.get(i).getLastName());
ps.setLong(3, actors.get(i).getId().longValue());
}
public int getBatchSize() {
return actors.size();
}
});
return updateCounts;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ashok, i have confusion like if i have to implement the BatchPreparedStatementSetter interface to a class so how can i can the ps object. I know we can make a parameterized constractor of that class for object passing, but from where ill get the ps object. Might be it through null pointer exception in that class when trying to do ps.setString.