# How to set columns value as Arraylist in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Here I want to set   2 columns values from list so i can update multiple rows at a time  I tried this but it's not working.

```
String hql = "UPDATE empDTO set empstatus =(:status) , empreason = 
            (:reason) WHERE enpID=(:id) and createdOn =:CreatedOn ";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameterList("status", status);//status is list
            query.setParameterList("reason", reason);//reason is list
            query.setParameterList("id", id);//id is list
            query.setParameter("CreatedOn",new Date());
             query.executeUpdate();
            rowAffected = query.executeUpdate();
```

org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute update query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: If reason is a list, the clause `empreason = (:reason)` makes no sense. Same for status. An employee has only one status, right, so setting an employee's status to a list doesn't make sense.

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s) and see updated question

Comment: @JBNizet im curious to know is it possible to do with where in query ?

Comment: You should first explain **what** you're trying to achieve. With a concrete example. If you want to update N employees, each with a different reason and a different status, then you need N queries. Or better, you need to load these N employees, set their poperties, and let Hibernate update the database for you.

Comment: @JB Nizet  for particular ids i am setting status and both id and status are in list

Comment: HQL translates to SQL. You can't do `update emp set status = 'a', 'b', 'c', reason = 'x', 'y', 'z' where id in (1, 2, 3)`. That is not valid SQL. Valid SQL would be 3 queries of the form: `update emp set status = 'a', reason = 'x' where id = 1`.

Comment: @JB Nizet I know how to do using N query for N ids but i want to reduce my DB hitting because for 1 lakh id i need to hit my DB 1 lack time so am trying to enhance my query so that db hitting reduces

Comment: can u suggest  better1 for updating multi rows at a time

Comment: @Priya does the empstatus , empreason has multiple values?

Comment: @soorapadman it  has  single value only eg: for  1 id 1 empstatus and 1empreason and my problem is for 20 ids i need to update 20 times to i am searching to enhance my code so that i can reduce DB hitting

Comment: @soorapadman ,@JB Nizet i want update 10 ids at a time

Comment: I want to make sure  You mean for `ID= 1`  reason='x', status='a' ,`ID= 2`  reason='y', status='b' ?

Comment: yes!!!! you are right

Comment: I could recommand `JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate`it is easy to to that .

Comment: can u write an example in answer

Comment: This is the one which will suit for your requirement :http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BatchPreparedStatementSetter.html

Comment: Check this link  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321784/what-is-the-use-of-this-spring-class-batchpreparedstatementsetter

Comment: but i am using struts2 framework

Comment: it doesn't matter you can still use jdbcTemplate  in Hibernate only concern here your changes in DAO .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you [BatchPreparedStatementSetter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BatchPreparedStatementSetter.html) to do the

You create a DTO to update a list of employeeUpdateDTO,

```
public class EmployeeUpdateDTO {
    private Integer empId;
    private String reason;
    private String status;

    public Integer getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(Integer empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Add this to your Implementation ;

```
    public void updateEmployee(List<EmployeeUpdateDTO> employeeUpdateDTOs) {
            String updateQuery = "UPDATE empDTO set empstatus =?,empreason =? WHERE enpID=? and createdOn =?";
            try {
                int[] updateCounts = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(updateQuery,
                        new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {

                                ps.setInt(1, employeeUpdateDTOs.get(i).empId);
                                ps.setString(2, employeeUpdateDTOs.get(i).getReason());
                                ps.setString(3, employeeUpdateDTOs.get(i).getStatus());
 ps.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
                            }

                            public int getBatchSize() {
                                return employeeUpdateDTOs.size();
                            }
                        });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
```

Comment: which pluggins i have to use

Comment: `spring-jdbc` you should use